# Trouble passing ArrayList to another Activity

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, arraylist, parameters

Good evening , I'm having trouble passing a ListView an Activity to another. The Activity code that passes to the other is the following called FiltrarImoveis.class :

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                    Imovel imv = new Imovel();

                    JSONObject child = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String finalidade=child.getString("finalidadeImovel");

                    String tipo = child.getString("tipoImovel");

                    String genero = child.getString("generoImovel");

                    String descricao = child.getString("descricaoImovel");

                    String responsavel = child.getString("responsavelImovel");

                    String telefoneResponsavel = child.getString("telefoneResponsavel");

                    String situacaoImovel = child.getString("situacaoImovel");

                    String valor = child.getString("valor");
                    imv.setFinalidade(finalidade);
                    imv.setTipo(tipo);
                    imv.setGenero(genero);
                    imv.setDescricao(descricao);
                    imv.setResponsavel(responsavel);
                    imv.setTelefoneResponsavel(telefoneResponsavel);
                    imv.setSituacao(situacaoImovel);
                    imv.setValor(valor);

                    listaImovel.add(imv);
                }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //showParsedJSON.setText(output);
        carregar(listaImovel);

    }
}
}

public void carregar(ArrayList<Imovel> listaImovel){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,DetalhesImoveis.class);
    intent.putExtra("lista",listaImovel);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

The class that inherits from the ListView is the following , call DetalhesImoveis.class :

```
private ListView lvImoveis;
ArrayList<Imovel> listaImoveis;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_detalhes_imoveis);

listaImoveis = (ArrayList<Imovel>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("lista");
lvImoveis = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvImoveis);

try {
    ArrayAdapter<Imovel> adpImovel = new ArrayAdapter<Imovel>(DetalhesImoveis.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listaImoveis);

    lvImoveis.setAdapter(adpImovel);
    //Log.v("LISTAiMOVEIS", "ELEMENTOS DA LISTA: " +listaImoveis.get(0).getDescricao().toString() );
}catch(Exception e){
    Log.v("logs","ERROR CAUSED BY THE EXCEPTION LIST: "+e.toString());
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

We should not use `putExtra()`for ArrayList instead of that use `putStringArrayListExtra()` eg: 
`public void carregar(ArrayList<Imovel> listaImovel){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,DetalhesImoveis.class);
    intent.putStringArrayListExtra("lista",listaImovel);`

and in  DetalhesImoveis.class get the Arraylist like:
`listaImoveis = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("lista");`

Comment: but with intent.putStringArrayListExtra , it expects an Array of type String

Comment: I don't know why you are using `<Imovel>` , the values you are adding in `listaImovel` are String only. so you can pass it as String itself.

Comment: I found , the error was in webservice that returns JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

u can :

```
    getIntent().putParcelableArrayListExtra(listaImovel)
      Imovel need to implment Parcelable
```

u can look sth about Parcelable;
or : 
    AActvt Put list int application or a static var ;
    BActvt get list from application or a static var;